# JavaFX controller class not found at Runtime

Tags: java, javafx, runtime, classnotfoundexception

I'm coding a JavaFX application that works with plugins.

I made a plugin that loads a fxml file to add some node in the main application.

I load the .jar containing all the .class of the plugin but when I run the plugin I have this exception :

[image: Exception]

I don't understand why because the .jar contains 'MainController.class'... but the java runtime can not find it when loading the fxml file.

When I run the plugin as a JavaFX standalone application it works fine.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace in the question, as [formatted text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), not as a link to a screenshot. Additionally, post the FXML file (or at least the root element) with the `fx:controller` attribute. You say the jar includes `MainController`, but that is not the class the `FXMLLoader` is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this :

Instead of declaring the contoller class in the FXML file, just set it programatically before loading the file like this :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getRessource("myFile.fxml");
loader.setController(new MyController());
loader.load();
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question though. There is no reason for the other method to fail if this one works (since the controller class is clearly on the classpath) unless you have something wrong. (So this is not a solution, it's a workaround.)

Comment: I think it is because the runtime loader used to load the fxml file can't access the .jar so it can't find the .class, but when you write it in the code then it is found because the .class file where you set the controller is already in the .jar. It's the only logic I see there ^^

Comment: I would have thought it was because the FXML has the wrong controller class name, as I pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. You're genius. I had the save problem when using JavaFX from OSGi application (JavaFX was loaded as a system bundle, so `FXMLLoader`'s class loader couldn't load my classes in other bundles). Your workaround worked and brought me enthusiasm, then I improved `loader.setController(…)` to `loader.setClassLoader(MyApp.class.getClassLoader())` and finally to `FXMLLoader.setDefaultClassLoader(MyApp.class.getClassLoader())`.